# error in applying auto increment by 1 on specific column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table name article and a column name articleid. I want that every time i enter the data in the table then value in column of articleid should be incremented to 1. I am trying to do like this.

```
ALTER TABLE article  MODIFY COLUMN articleid INT auto_increment
```

But it generates this error statement:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '=1' at line 1

Comment: And the error would be??

Comment: it saying that  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '=1' at line 1

Comment: Can you post the current table definition?

Comment: @Jeremy sorry what you meant from definition?

Comment: What is the create table statement used to create the article table?

Comment: article(
   articletitle VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY ( articleid )
);

Comment: i have created the table already now i want to alter the table and want to apply auto increment on its column

Comment: yes it was used to create article table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error message is

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '=1' at line 1

But the query you've shown us is

```
ALTER TABLE article  MODIFY COLUMN articleid INT auto_increment
```

Note `=1` is not in the query you've shown us, so you are running some code that you are not intentionally trying to run. The syntax for your `ALTER TABLE` query looks correct.

---

**Update:** To ensure your MySQL increment by 1, set the MySQL configuration setting of `auto_increment_increment = 1`. Note in MySQL, this is a global setting and not a table or column setting.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-options-master.html#sysvar_auto_increment_increment

Comment: how can i make the increment of only one. Because the statement which i have shown above is incrementing the more than one.like (1,4,7,15)

Answer (score 0):

A working SQL Statement to accomplish this is:

`ALTER TABLE  article CHANGE  articleid  articleid INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT`
Please make sure that you've assigned the Primary key to the column 'articled'

If not, run this statement:
`ALTER TABLE article ADD PRIMARY KEY(articled)`
Because auto_increment can only be applied to the column that is the primary key of your table.

If it's not working at all, you could just start over by dropping your table (all data is lost!)

`DROP TABLE article`

And re-create it with all properties and keys assigned properly.

```
CREATE TABLE article (
articleid int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
articletitle varchar(100) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (articleid)
)
```

Comment: first i used this statement but it's does not increment only one value  i want to generate the increment of plus one